# How do I use different replacement texts for a pattern found multiple times

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, replace

**sample log file:**

```
apple AAA rose
banana AAA tulip
orange AAA marigold
```

**replacement-text file:**

```
111
222
333
```

**Expected output:**

```
apple 111 rose
banana 222 tulip
orange 333 marigold
```

Comment: Any attempts / ideas / thoughts from your side?

Comment: `perl -lpe '
   chomp(@A=qx/cat repl.txt/) if $. == 1;
    s/\h\KAAA(?=\h)/shift @A/e;
' input.txt`

Answer (score 1):

There are umpteen ways to skin a cat. Let's assume the connection between both files is on line No.  Try e.g. this one, which `paste`s lines together and then shifts the trailing word to the field containing `AAA` using regex ""back references":

```
paste sample_log replacement-text | sed -r 's/AAA ([^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*)(.*$)/\2 \1/'
apple 111 rose  
banana 222 tulip    
orange 333 marigold
```

or this one, which makes `awk` read the replacements into an array, and then replaces the second field by the respective array element:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {T[NR] = $0; next } {$2 = T[FNR]} 1' replacement-text sample_log 
apple 111 rose
banana 222 tulip
orange 333 marigold
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash 
paste logfile.txt replacement.txt | while IFS= read -r line; do

echo $line | sed "s/`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`/`echo $line | awk '{print $4}'`/g" | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " "}'

done
```